# Can not Build and View pdfLatex for the first time in windows

Tags: miktex, texstudio

I've just installed MikTex and then TexStudio but I can not compile a simple code like `\documentclass{article}` in texStudio and gives error :

[image]

and this is the log pointing to :

```
2021-02-14 13:03:48,278+0330 INFO  pdflatex - this process (9136) started by 'texstudio' with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test1.tex
2021-02-14 13:03:48,286+0330 WARN  pdflatex - security risk: running with elevated privileges
2021-02-14 13:03:48,293+0330 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-02-14 13:03:48,326+0330 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2021-02-14 13:03:48,361+0330 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2021-02-14 13:03:49,395+0330 ERROR pdflatex - C:\Users\z.gh\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2021-02-14 13:03:49,395+0330 ERROR pdflatex - output:
2021-02-14 13:03:49,395+0330 ERROR pdflatex - initexmf: security risk: running with elevated privileges

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\z.gh\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2021-02-14 13:03:49,395+0330 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-02-14 13:03:49,395+0330 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-02-14 13:03:49,396+0330 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:717
2021-02-14 13:03:49,396+0330 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-02-14 13:03:49,396+0330 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-02-14 13:03:49,396+0330 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-02-14 13:03:49,396+0330 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 717
2021-02-14 13:03:49,396+0330 INFO  pdflatex - this process (9136) finishes with exit code 1
```

How can I fix the problem ?

Comment: miktex can't create the format.  You need to find out why not. As security is mentioned: it could be e.g. some overeager virus protection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the solutions of similar problem and non of them worked,

then by **Updating** **my Window 10** it worked!